# QUECTEL M95 Send HTTP POST with JSON

Tags: json, http, post, gsm

I need some support for sending an http post with json content type application.
This is my code:

```
AT+CPIN=####
AT+QIDNSIP=1
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","xxx"
AT+QIOPEN="TCP","yyy",80
AT+QHTTPURL=55,10
zzz
AT+QHTTPCFG="requestheader",1
AT+QHTTPPOST=188,30,60
POST /api/ooo HTTP/1.1
HOST:https://qqq.net
Accept: /
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
{'field1':'val1','field2':'val2'}
```

But I always receive the 3822 error code.

Obviously, the WEB API works correctly because it has been used in another service.

Where's the problem into my code?

Has anyone resolved a similar issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very long time after you asked, but..
As far as I see you are missing a newline between:

Content-Type: application/json
{'field1':'val1','field2':'val2'}

Also I had the same issue as you had, but managed to solve it now. Though I did wait for CONNECT after sending QHTTPPOST, I actually had to wait some more time after receiving CONNECT (i did a delay of 300 milliseconds) and then it worked :-)
You also do not have Content-Length, but this would not result in 3822, I would guess the delay between CONNECT and when you send data